# Collapse a PageBlockSection once a commandlink has been pressed

Tags: apex, visualforce, jquery

I have been asked to have a pageblocksection minimize as soon as commandlink has been pressed to make our page look less crammed. So far I have set the area I need to minimize to collapsible true and id to "updateCollapsible" and tried to rerender the commandlink. However, this didn't work. Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
<td>
  <apex:commandLinkvalue="{!reducedCategoryMap[ReducedSingle].specificProductComponent.displayName__c}" 
    action="{!getSpecificPOCompFieldValueLinkWrapperListByComponent}" 
    oncomplete="resizeInputs()" 
    rerender="Overall, Save, SaveProdOrder, fields, blurgh, updateCollapsible" status="loading3" >
    <apex:param value="{!ReducedSingle}" assignTo="{!uniqueRef}" name="uniqueComponent"/>
  </apex:commandLink>
</td>
<apex:pageblocksection columns="2" collapsible="true" title="Product Order Overview" id="updateCollapsible">
  <img src="/img/loading.gif" alt="Loading graphic" style="display:none" id="loadingImg"/>
  <apex:outputText value="" />
  <apex:outputField value="{!updateProductOrder.Project__r.Name}" label="Project Name" />
  <div id="updatebutton">
    <apex:commandButton value="Update" action="{!updateProductOrderValues}" rerender="aaa" status="loading" />
  </div>
</apex:pageblocksection>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dan,

you can use this [Salesforce Help](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000181821&language=en_US) as a reference and extend the solution to something like below.

this reference article talks about having the pageblock collapsed by default during page load by having the script called onload.

I just moved it out as separate function and calling it from commandbutton. you can do the same with commandlink as well.

```
<apex:page >
<script> 
function expandCollapse(){
 twistSection(document.getElementById('{!$Component.theForm.block1.section1}').getElementsByTagName('img')[0]); 
}
</script>
<apex:form id="theForm">
<apex:commandButton value="Click Me" onclick="expandCollapse(); return false;"/>
<apex:pageBlock id="block1">
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="section1" columns="2" collapsible="true" title="Title">
        Example Area
    </apex:pageBlockSection>    
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```